# Excel 2007 VBA to merge multiple sheets to 1 with a column offset

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I have found TONS of answers on how to exclude column headings when merging sheets but I can't find any answers on how to exclude column A after the initial sheet is copied.  Please help.  Warning:  I am very new to VBA and I may have done something silly but I have been trying to make this work for 2 days.  I keep getting the error with the last two lines of code before the end if statements. My first time ever posting a question so advise if better way to do this.

Simple description of what I want:

- **NOTE**:  All sheets always have 365 rows, number of sheets and number of columns vary.
- Take Sheet one and copy data to new "Master" sheet, all columns and all rows
- All other sheets will have the exact same Column A, but need to take B through unknown number of columns and add to the next vacant column in the Master sheet.

**example**:
Sheet 1 has 365 rows and only column A and column B
Sheet 2 has 365 rows and columns A through D have data
New Master sheet has 365 rows and contains everything from Sheet 1 and columns B through H from Sheet 2 would add to the master sheet as columns C through E

**Here's my code:**

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim DataRng As Range
Dim Col As Long
Dim Cnt As Integer

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Report").Delete
Sheets("Wex").Delete
Sheets("C Locs").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0
Sheets.Add().Name = "Master"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Cnt = 1

Set wsMain = Worksheets("Master")
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

If ws.Name <> wsMain.Name Then
If Cnt = 1 Then
Set DataRng = ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
DataRng.Copy wsMain.Cells(1, Cnt)
Else: Col = wsMain.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

DataRng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(DataRng.Rows.Count, DataRng.Columns.Count - 1).Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Col)

End If
End If
Cnt = Cnt + 1
Next ws



Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> wsMain.Name Then
        If Cnt = 1 Then
            Set DataRng = ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            DataRng.Copy wsMain.Cells(1, 1)
        Else
            With ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                Set DataRng = .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1)
                DataRng.Copy wsMain.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
            End With
        End If

        Cnt = Cnt + 1
    End If

Next ws
```